# Error when run WPF Application in other Computer

Tags: c#, wpf

First of all, I am new to WPF application.
I have create WPF application login form which require input username and password from the users. This application then will open new form if the username and password matching with the one on sql server database.

```
    private void Login_bt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {   
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\\isdsvr04\LED\LDEMPDB\MPDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From [Table] 
            where Username='" + username_tx.Text + "' and Password='" + 
            password_tx.Text + "'", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Globals.username = username_tx.Text;
                Globals.FullName = dt.Rows[0]["FullName"].ToString();
                Globals.userImage = dt.Rows[0]["UserImage"].ToString();
                Globals.NickName = dt.Rows[0]["NickName"].ToString();

                this.Hide();
                Window1 f = new Window1();
                f.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please check your username and password");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException == null ? ex.Message : ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
        
    }
```

'''

This work fine on my PC. However when I run this on other PC, the exception generate error "The systems cannot find the file specified". The sql server database is located on the public server in which all computer can access through it.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the users running this program have access not just to the folder the file is in, but they have read/write access to the database file itself?

Comment: How to check whether they have read/write access to the database file itself?

Comment: First of all you not have SQL Server database. You have mdf file wich inpose restriction to all PC, where your application will work - all PC must have network connection to share, all users wich will execute your application can open this share and see your mdf file in explorer. Than, all users that executing your app must have access to read/write to file, and you must resolve concurrency problem with acccess users to data in file.

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that the code here has a number of security flaws. That may or may not be important in this application, but they are bad habits that you should learn to avoid. The way you form your SQL statement leaves it wide open to [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). You also appear to be storing passwords in plain text which is definitely one of the ways [not to store passwords](https://itnext.io/how-not-to-store-passwords-4955569e6e84).